# Using expressions to define validation rules

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I want to create a generic validation class, so I can do something like:

```
Validation v = new Validation();
v.AddRequired(x => this.Name);
v.AddRange(x => x.this.Age, 5, 65);
```

I'm unsure as to how to write the method definition and make the evaluation?

Where `AddRequired` would take a `string` and `AddRange` would take a numeric type (`int`, primarily but also `double`, `decimal`, etc)

Comment: What should `AddRequired` and `AddRange` do?

Comment: If you are not mad set on implementing it yourself, I'd recommend FluentValidation: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation. It's a very flexible library for validations

Comment: Give also a look to Code Contracts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why don't you extend the already existing [ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617871.aspx) class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach would be:

```
class ObjectToBeValidated {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Validation {
    private List<Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, bool>>> requiredExpressions;
    private List<Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, bool>>> rangeExpressions;

    public void AddRequired(Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, string>> expression)
    {
        Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, bool>> checkRequired = (p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression.Compile().Invoke(p)));
        requiredExpressions.Add(checkRequired);
    }

    public void AddRange(Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, int>> expression, int min, int max)
    {
        Func<ObjectToBeValidated, int> compiledFunc = expression.Compile();
        Expression<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, bool>> checkRange = (p => compiledFunc.Invoke(p) >= min && compiledFunc.Invoke(p) < max);
        rangeExpressions.Add(checkRange);
    }
}
```

This would just store your conditions in `List<T>`'s.
You then would have to add a method to your `Validation` class to evaluate the expressions:

```
public bool IsValid(ObjectToBeValidated testObject)
    {
        return requiredExpressions.All(p => p.Compile().Invoke(testObject))
            && rangeExpressions.All(p => p.Compile().Invoke(testObject));
    }
```

Then use like this:

```
validator.AddRequired(p => p.Name);
validator.AddRange(p => p.Age, 6, 15);

var myObject = new ObjectToBeValidated();
var result = validator.IsValid(myObject);
```

Comment: Of course, you could also compile the expressions in the `AddRequired` and `AddRange methods` already, add them to a `List<Func<ObjectToBeValidated, bool>>`, and just invoke them in the `IsValid` function. Also, you could use one List of those for all conditions instead one for each condition type like in my example.

Answer (score 1):

There should be some libraries available for this task. However, you can get some experience with lambdas by writing this yourself. I have made a draft implementation for the `AddRange`, I hope you can go further from here.

```
    public class Validation<T> {
        private List<RangeValidation> _rangeValidations = new List<RangeValidation>();

        public void AddRange(Func<T, int> func, int min, int max) {
            _rangeValidations.Add(new RangeValidation() {
                func = func,
                min = min,
                max = max
            });
        }

        public bool Validate(T obj) {
            foreach (var rangeValidation in _rangeValidations) {
                int value = rangeValidation.func(obj);
                if (value < rangeValidation.min || value > rangeValidation.max)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private class RangeValidation {
            public Func<T, int> func;
            public int min, max;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Validation` generic on the type of `x`, define methods taking `Func<x,object>` or some other type as needed, store these functions, and call them from the `Validate(x)` method:

```
class Validation<T> {
    private IList<Tuple<Func<T,IComparable>,IComparable,IComparable>> rangeChecks = new List<Tuple<Func<T,IComparable>,IComparable,IComparable>>();
    private IList<Func<T,object>> nullChecks = new List<Func<T,object>>;
    public AddRequired(Func<T,object> f) {
        nullChecks.Add(f);
    }
    public AddRange(Func<T,IComparable> f, IComparable low, IComparable high) {
        rangeChecks.Add(Tuple.Create(f, low, high));
    }
    public bool Validate(T x) {
        foreach(var t in rangeChecks) {
            var f = t.Item1;
            var low = t.Item2;
            var high = t.Item3;
            var val = f(x);
            if (v.CompareTo(low) < 0 || v.CompareTo(high) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        foreach (var t in nullChecks) {
            if (t(x) == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This implementation is very skeletal - it needs null checks in many places to be useful. In addition, it's not very efficient, because `IComparable` and `object` could wrap value types. However, the way of passing and storing `Func<T,...>` objects should give you an idea of how to implement the rest of it.